# Starting point for Oauth and Twitter API (for iOS development)

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, oauth

I would love to know where to start to understand how to integrate Twitter in my iPhone applications.

So here are a few questions:

- Is it madness trying to implement anything without an Oauth library?
- Which of [these methods](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens) should I use to obtain an access token (I want to open safari.app and get redirected back to my application using iOS url schemes, à la Twitterific)?
- Can I avoid browser based authentication with iOS 5 Twitter integration?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with requiring iOS 5, than Twitter.framework is the best/easiest way to go. They handle OAuth and everything for you. Everything is done simply by using `TWRequest`. It's very simple.

If you need to support older versions of iOS, than you should take a look at MGTwitterEngine. I believe that there are some forks of it on github that incorporate OAuth.

But with that being said, I highly recommend that you just target iOS 5 and forget iOS 4. It will make implementing Twitter much easier. If you need convincing, check out Matt Gemmell's blog post about why it's okay to only support the latest operating system: http://mattgemmell.com/2011/12/05/latest-version/

EDIT: And yes, Twitter.framework handles authentication for you. No need to use the browser. But users will need to add their Twitter accounts in the Settings app beforehand. If you want them to be able to add accounts through your app, then I believe you need to handle authentication yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will go ios 5 only as you suggested. Oauth is a big pain to manage for a newbie. ;)